# creating a dropdownlist in mvc 5 in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlistitem

**Hi, I am having trouble creating a dropdown list in mvc5,
This is what I have in my model:**

```
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public LocationChecker()
{
    PopulateCountryCodes();
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryCodes { get; set; }

private void PopulateCountryCodes()
{
    CountryCodes = new List<SelectListItem>();
    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text =“UK”});

    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text =“GB”});

    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text =“IRL”});
}
```

**and this is my view:**

```
<h4>Countries</h4>
  add a drop down list

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryCode, Model.CountryCodes)
</div>
```

the ADD in  CountryCodes.Add is red and cannot be resolved and also I have "expression expected" error further down the line just before UK,GB and IRL.

any help will be appreciated please. This is the first time I am using mvc5 btw.

Thanks

Nav

Answer (score 1):

I can see a problem, the quote character is not quite right for the Text property.

Where you have this:

```
    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text =“UK”});

    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text =“GB”});

    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text =“IRL”});
```

Try this instead:

```
    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text ="UK"});

    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text ="GB"});

    CountryCodes.Add (new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text ="IRL"});
```

Comment: There is no difference in calling `new SelectListItem()` or `new SelectListItem{}` parameterless constructor is called in both scenarious

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I have changed it too                CountryCodes.Add(new SelectListItem() {Value = "England"});                      It has remove the expression error but ADD is still in red. any help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

In the back end, build a SelectList

```
countryCodes = new List<SelectListItem>();
countryCodes.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "theText", Value = "TheValue" });
```

Assign to your view model (this is in the constructor, hence 'this')

```
this.CountryCodes = new SelectList(countryCodes, "Value", "Text", "Please Select");
```

And in the front end (CountryCode is an int, a member of your view model)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, this.Model.CountryCodes, new { placeholder = "Please select a Country Code", @class = "form-control", name = "CountryCodeSelected" })
```